# How can I get Python's code coloring for Go code in VS code?

Tags: python, go, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I use One Dark Pro in vs code. When I'm writing in a python file, everything has a distinct color, it's wonderful.

In a Go file, there are many similarities to the Python coloring (because of course I'm still using One Dark Pro, for example def and func are both purple) but much of the code is in plain white.

It seems to be variables, though packages and struct literals go white as well.

Is there a way to get the Python coloring in Go?

[image: Python Code]

[image: Go Code]

Comment: then you have to modify the TextMate file of your Go language extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify in the `settings.json` file using:

```json
// Just an example

    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Abyss]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "meta.function-call",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#ffffff"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "scope": "entity.name.type, entity.name.class, entity.name.namespace, entity.name.scope-resolution",
                    "settings": {
                        "fontStyle": ""
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    },
```

*Use **Ctrl** + **Space** as you write and you'll get more configuration suggestions to use.*

Comment: For those of you who are interested

        "[One Dark Pro]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "source.go",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#e06c75"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }